# Approach for Load Menu from Json/XML file with good memory utilization

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a menu file "navigationMenu.json" for my asp.net MVC application. Here is how i read the json file

```
public static class NavigationMenu
{
 public static List<NavigationMenuViewModel> Get()
        {
            string jsonMenu  = File.ReadAllText(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/navigationmenu.json"));

            var menu = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NavigationMenuViewModel>>(jsonMenu);
            return menu;
        } 
}
```

So now when a page loads this method `NavigationMenu.Get()` called everytime and used in the view to display the menu.

My concern is, if this is the right way. Should i be using a static List Object to store the menu and use the list instead of reading everytime from the file? Also any changes in the menu file needs to show up instantly too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can depend on various things. If this file is accessed by 4 people every hour, there's no point over-engineering. Reading from a file is acceptable.

If you can ensure a single point of access to the file which is from your application (no other process touches it, like notepad), you can easily cache the contents and invalidate/refresh when accessing from said single point of access.

If there's a lot of traffic and can't ensure controlled access, you could also have a cache with a few seconds of expiration. I assume the users can live for 3 seconds with stale data. Also if the app only requests the navigation at the initial load, a lot of users will miss out on the update until they do a full-page refresh.